# input type=number for username login and saving password

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, webkit, progressive-web-apps

Consider this form

```
<form action="/user" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div>
<input placeholder="Mobile number" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60" type="number">
<input placeholder="Password" type="text" name="pass" size="60" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" name="op" value="LOGIN">
</form>
```

In my app, I use phone number for the user's login. I want to have the number keypad show for this input so instead of `input type=text` we use `input type=number`

However, this is causing issues with certain browsers seemingly not recognizing this field as a username, and so it is no longer providing a dropdown autocomplete in username and populating the below `input type=password` when I am on chrome mobile.

The dropdown autocomplete username, which populates the password is visible and working on Chrome desktop but not Chrome mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the autocomplete attribute to help the browsers understand what is going on. This should help out.

```html
<div class="md-form">
   <input type="tel" class="form-control validate" name="Username" tabindex="20"
                        autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
   <label for="Username">Username</label>
</div>
```

I am not sure what extension I have installed in VS Code, but as I type the attribute it then gives me possible values to drive this.

You should also note you can add an aria attribute around this as well. For that you may need to add a list of options, I have not checked into how to drive that.

Comment: Thanks for answering this Chris I have been a big fan of your writing for a while.  We think autocomplete="name" helped the most in this case. But it still isn't saving 100% as if it was a standard text input.

Comment: I wonder if the tel type triggers some other behavior in relation to the username. You need to constrain to digits and want the number pad visible. But in the browser's mind a username is text.

Comment: Yeah was wondering the same. Found this documentation. Google uses a heuristic system to determine how to save passwords and lists best practices here. https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands Doesn't mention anything about tel type though. Also this for Safari https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element